# R is a commutative ring with unity 1 s.t. $x^9 = 0$. Does this imply anything about (1-x)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

In the midst of studying for my abstract algebra midterm, I stumbled about this question.

> If R is a commutative ring with unity such that $x^9 = 0$, is it necessarily true that $(1-x)$ is a unit?

I haven't made a lot of progress aside from noticing that x is a zero divisor and 1 is not. I don't know if that's relevant to this problem or not. I would appreciate any and all guidance on how to start.

Another idea I had was trying to show that $(1-x)^m$ for any $m \in Z^+$ is non-zero (since there is always the constant term of 1 in the expansion) but that didn't really get me anywhere either.

Comment: Hint: consider $1-x^9$ as a polynomial.

Comment: @RolfHoyer That's as good a hint as any---perhaps promote it to a full answer?

Comment: @RolfHoyer I think I got it now thank you!

Comment: More generally, if $x$ is nilpotent, then $1-x$ is invertible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for the hint @RolfHoyer.

\begin{alignat}{2}
1 &= 1 - 0 \\
&= 1 - x^9 &\text {  by hypothesis} \\
&= (1-x)(x^8 + x^7 + \cdots +1).
\end{alignat}
Since R is commutative, 
$$ 1= (1-x)(x^8 + x^7 + \cdots +1) = (x^8 + x^7 + \cdots +1)(x-1)$$ and thus $$(x^8 + x^7 + \cdots +1)$$ is $$(1-x)^{-1}$$

Comment: Stating that $1+x+\dots+x^8\ne0$ is not necessary: it follows from $(1-x)(1+x+\dots+x^8)=1$. Note that commutativity of $R$ is not required, because all happens in the subring generated by $x$, which is commutative  anyway.

Answer (score 2):

My hint is to consider the polynomial $1-x^9$.